# What is the correct way to call this function and pass this array via a segue?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass an array from `loginViewController` to `ViewController` using a segue.

The array is `communtiesArray` and is fetched in this section of code:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                    self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]! }
                }
               print ("first test: ",self.communitiesArray) // This prints values OK.
```

As stated, this debug test prints correctly.  I now try to pass `communities.Array` through a segue to ViewController in this function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let createViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        createViewController.communities = communitiesArray
        print("second test: ", communitiesArray) //this prints nothing
    }    
}
```

I feel I must going wrong in my use of this as an `override func`as it did not seem to get called as `print` debug does not activate.

This is the full userLogin script:

```
import UIKit

protocol UsernameSentDelegate {
func userLoggedIn(data: String)
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: UsernameSentDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var displayUserName: UILabel!
var communitiesArray  = [String]()


@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    if (userPassword!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty) { return; }

// send user data to server side

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/userLogin.php");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
               if(error != nil)
                {

                    //Display an alert message
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                    if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]! }
                    }
                   print ("first test: ",self.communitiesArray) // This print correctly in debug

                    // retrieve login details and check to see if all ok

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                        if(returnValue != "error")
                        {

                            self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: userEmail! )

                            UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                        } else {
                            // display an alert message
                            let userMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    }
                } catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }

        }

    }

    task.resume()

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let createViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        createViewController.communities = communitiesArray
        print("second test: ", communitiesArray) //this prints nothing
    }

}


}
```

In reference to the error I am receiving as stated in comments section, this is the code from `ViewController` that contains the variable for line `createViewController.communities = sender as? Array`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource, UsernameSentDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var receiveUsername: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailText: UILabel!
var userEmail: String?
var communities = [String]() // this is the target of the segue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz perform segue like this

```
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self.communitiesArray)
```

and in prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let createViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        createViewController.communities = sender as? Array

    }

}
```

Comment: I have overcome a slight problem with the segue, but I am now getting this error:  Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x1086d77a0) to 'NSArray' (0x1073bdc58).
(lldb)  on this line:    createViewController.communities = (sender as? Array)!

Comment: slightly edited the line in question to:  createViewController.communities = communitiesArray .this solved that error.  All done :)